# Closed map $T:X \to Y$ has closed graph?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, closed-graph

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator between two normed vector spaces. My question is:

> If $T$ is a closed map (sends closed sets to closed), then is the graph of $T$ a closed set of $X \times Y$?

It seems to be the case according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326902), even if the converse [is not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988137). I haven't found a counter-example.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is true for every continuous map between separated space, the converse of this assertion is the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @TsemoAristide : thank you. 1. Ah yes, for instance [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367155). But if $T$ is not assumed to be continuous, but only linear? $\tag*{}$ 2. For the converse, don't we need $X$ and $Y$ to be Banach spaces? For me, the closed graph theorem tells us that the graph of $T$ is closed iff $T$ is continuous. In particular, I would get that $T$ is closed?